# Oracle error: Error 28000 - Account locked

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In spite of unlocking several times, my account on oracle database is getting locked each time I try to connect to another user.

I type the following command while I am on root account:

```
sql> connect hr/hr
```

And then, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: ORA-28000: the account is locked
WARNING: You are no longer connected to ORACLE
```

Comment: How did you unlock several times? What exactly did you do?

Comment: *Your* account isn't being locked. The HR account is locked. You need to unlock that one, not your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to connect to a locked account:this is not permitted. However, issuing a `connect` logs you out of your root account (whatever means in an Oracle context).

In order to connect to `hr` you need to unlock that account. This needs DBA privileges:

```
alter user hr account unlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME parameter by using below command.

```
alter profile default limit PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME  unlimited;
```